# Календарь в форме ввода даты php (Yii2)

Tags: php, yii2, виджет, календарь

Здравствуйте.

Хотелось бы сделать форму, где нужно будет вводить дату, а так же, для удобства, чтобы сбоку открывался календарь для выбора даты, листая по месяцам и годам, после чего сохранять выбранную дату в БД.

Пример реализации: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии, высвечивалось что-то по по типу такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как будет лучше реализовать это? Что посоветуете?

Фреймвор Yii2, для отображение формы используется виджет DetailView.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё уже сделано. Вообще у этого парня много полезного.

> http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker

Comment: Спасибо большое, что указали ресурс откуда брать. )